# Jest mock promise rejection to enforce rejection in calling function

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to test the following `get` function using Jest. How can test / mock the Promise rejection in `localForage.getItem`, so that I can test the `get` `catch` block?

```js
async get<T>(key: string): Promise<T | null> {
  if (!key) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('There is no key to get!'));
  }

  try {
    return await this.localForage.getItem(key);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('The key (' + key + ") isn't accessible.");
  }
}
```

I tried the following:

```js
  test('test get promise rejection', async () => {
    const expectedError = new Error(
      'The key (' + 'fghgdfghfghfdh' + ") isn't accessible."
    );
    jest.fn(localforage.getItem).mockRejectedValue(new Error());
    expect(get('fghgdfghfghfdh')).rejects.toThrow(expectedError);
  });
```

But I get the following error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: expect(received).rejects.toThrow()

Received promise resolved instead of rejected
Resolved to value: null".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, I had to replace `localforage.getItem` with `jest.fn().mockRejectedValue`:

```js
test('test get promise rejection', async () => {
  localforage.getItem = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error());

  const expectedError = new Error(
    'The key (' + 'fghgdfghfghfdh' + ") isn't accessible."
  );
  expect(handler.get('fghgdfghfghfdh')).rejects.toThrow(expectedError);
});
```

Comment: How did you solve for testing the code inside promise? `return Promise.reject...` ? I can see you can assert to test exception by mocking but you can't test any code inside the promise if you mock out the call. I am having similar problem where my tests pass but I get the same error as yours and looking for a way to test.

Answer (score 1):

Well... we remove the `await` keyword from this line

```
expect(await get('fghgdfghfghfdh')).rejects.toThrow(expectedError);
```

Because the error clearly states

> received value must be a promise or a function returning a promise

Then the test fails because it expected to be rejected and insted is resolved with `null` value

So, either invoke `get` without a key

```
 expect(get()).rejects.toThrow(expectedError);
```

Or make `get` function more defensive like this

```
async get<T>(key: string): Promise<T | null> {
  if (!key) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('There is no key to get!'));
  }

  try {
    const result = await this.localForage.getItem(key);
    if (result) return result;
    throw new Error('empty value');
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('The key (' + key + ") isn't accessible: ");
  }
}
```

Which approach to use? I think both... anyhow I do hope you manage with your tests!

Comment: I want to test specifically the `catch` block that `throw new Error('The key (' + key + ") isn't accessible: ");`